# How do I make a library function in a plugin that is accessible by everything in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I would like to create a plugin library function that can be used anywhere in my rails app. I'm sure this must be very easy to do but I can not seem to find examples on how to do this. All the tutorials I've found so far show how to only extend classes or make methods that only work inside model or controllers.

Even [RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) does not seem to show how to do this.

Hey thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create a module or class method and then call that. For example:

```
module MySpecialModule
  def self.do_something
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end
```

Then, the following can be called from anywhere:

```
MySpecialModule.do_something
```

If you are really intent on having your do_something method be called from every single object in Ruby, then you can extend the object class like this:

```
class Object
  def do_something
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end

class K
end

K.new.do_something
=> hello world
```

You can use this same method to extend any base class, for example ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: Where in the plugin file structure would you place the module and what is the convention for naming the file?

Comment: You would place it in the lib directory. You follow the same conventions you would with creating a gem. You would name it according to the module or plugin my_class.rb (MyClass). Here's a good post about creating and publishing gems: http://blog.thepete.net/2010/11/creating-and-publishing-your-first-ruby.html